# Eclipse - Could not open JavaScript editor

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

I am getting the following error in Eclipse:

```
Could not open the editor. Editor could not be initialized (.js)
```

I am unable to open any `.js` files in Eclipse. I can open `.html` `.java` `.jsp` `.xml` files fine.

Error details:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.SetBuildpathOperation.generateBuildpathChangeDeltas(SetBuildpathOperation.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.SetBuildpathOperation.updateBuildpath(SetBuildpathOperation.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.SetBuildpathOperation.executeOperation(SetBuildpathOperation.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ModelOperation.run(ModelOperation.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ModelOperation.runOperation(ModelOperation.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ScriptProject.setRawBuildpath(ScriptProject.java:1947)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.core.DLTKCore$3.run(DLTKCore.java:2052)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ModelOperation.run(ModelOperation.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.core.DLTKCore.run(DLTKCore.java:1389)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.core.DLTKCore.setBuildpathContainer(DLTKCore.java:2028)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.launching.InterpreterContainerInitializer.initialize(InterpreterContainerInitializer.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ModelManager.initializeContainer(ModelManager.java:1824)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ModelManager.getBuildpathContainer(ModelManager.java:1654)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.core.DLTKCore.getBuildpathContainer(DLTKCore.java:1728)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ScriptProject.getResolvedBuildpath(ScriptProject.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ScriptProject.getResolvedBuildpath(ScriptProject.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ScriptProject.getResolvedBuildpath(ScriptProject.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ModelManager.determineIfOnBuildpath(ModelManager.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ModelManager.createSourceModuleFrom(ModelManager.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.core.ModelManager.create(ModelManager.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.core.DLTKCore.create(DLTKCore.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.ui.editor.SourceModuleDocumentProvider.createSourceModule(SourceModuleDocumentProvider.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.ui.editor.SourceModuleDocumentProvider.createFileInfo(SourceModuleDocumentProvider.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextFileDocumentProvider.connect(TextFileDocumentProvider.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.ui.editor.SourceModuleDocumentProvider.connect(SourceModuleDocumentProvider.java:1553)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1451)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.ui.editor.ScriptEditor.internalDoSetInput(ScriptEditor.java:1095)
    at org.ebayopensource.vjet.eclipse.internal.ui.editor.VjoEditor.internalDoSetInput(VjoEditor.java:1137)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.mod.internal.ui.editor.ScriptEditor.doSetInput(ScriptEditor.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3200)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow$1.run(ApplicationWindow.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.run(ApplicationWindow.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2649)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3218)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createSite(EditorManager.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2945)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2764)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

I'm new to eclipse, so I have absolutely no idea what any of this means.

Here are the `.js` editors inside `Window > Prefs > General > Editor > File Associations`:

- VJET Editor(default)(locked by "VJET Source File" content type)
- JavaScript Editor (locked by "JavaScript Source File" content type)
- Text Editor (locked by Javascriot Source File" content type)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using this build? http://eclipse.org/vjet/

Comment: I'm not sure but i was able to resolve issue by simply right clicking js files and selecting Open With JavaScript Editor

Comment: It certainly looks like there was a problem with that component, a reinstall of that software component may fix it.